# fetch data from an XML file between two different contents

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to fetch the data between two XML tags like

```
<page size="10" seconds="184" name="TEST_ONE" query="test environment">
  <content1>...</content1>
  <content2>...</content2>
</page>
```

I have tried

```
cat ABC.XML | grep -oP '(?<=<page size="10" seconds="184" name="TEST_ONE" query="test environment">).*?(?=</page>)'
```

But I get nothing. I tried with sed as well like

```
sed -e 's/<page size="10"\(.*\)page/\1/g'
```

But didn't get what I wanted. I want the content to be printed as below : 
...
...

can some one help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

`xmlstarlet` to the rescue!

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'page' ABC.XML
```

There is options for all kind of other formatting and querying.

If you want subelements, use

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c 'page/*' ABC.XML
```

And given your "query" answer in comment to other answer:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "page[@query='test environment']/*" ABC.XML
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
sed -e'1,/<page.*query="test environment">/ d' -e'/<\/page>/,$ d' abc1.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a `xml` parser. Here you have an example with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `XML::Twig` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => {
        'page[@query = "test environment"]/*' => sub { $_->print },
    },  
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( shift );
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
<content1>...</content1>
<content2>...</content2>
```

Comment: I have one more problem with this, I have multiple page tags in same XML. So I want to get a page which has a query named query="test environment". ? Will there be any space issues ?

Comment: @San: Edited to add the attribute condition `[@query = "test environment"]`.

Comment: Also, I have to give include "XML FILE" command right ? Hope this works.